# How to checkout repository on remote server using Jenkins Pipeline Script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to checkout repository into remote server, not into the slave/master which executes the job. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use pipeline steps on agents, so machines that don't have an agent installed will have to be dealt with using external tools. Alternatively, you can choose a mixed approach if it fits you: use the `checkout` step on a Jenkins node, then move the code to another server using a shell/batch command.